# Open many tooltips at once with JQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I need to do something like:

```
$(document).tooltip("open");
```

I need to do this because of I want display the tooltip on mouseover but also with a checkbox showing all of them.

Is this even possible?

You can check what I want in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3e5QP/

Comment: Maybe. You'll need to post the rest of the relevant code and if possible, create a jsFiddle.

Comment: Ok, here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/3e5QP/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine but you have a few issues with your example.

First, your checkbox has an id of `#showAll` when it should be simply `showAll`.

Second, according to the jQuery API, the [tooltip open method](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open) only works on non-delegated elements.

> Programmatically open a tooltip. This is only intended to be called
>   for non-delegated tooltips.

So instead of binding the tooltips to the document, bind them to your anchors.

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3e5QP/1/)** that shows all the tooltips when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Right, I've just misspelled the id. Thanks a lot